# Como rodar uma aplicação em várias Threads?

Tags: java, swing, thread

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com interface feita pelo Swing. A aplicação tem como por objetivo simular uma rede de computadores na qual irei monitorar usando a implementação `InetAddress`. Pois bem, criei minha interface, onde o usuário cadastra o nome da máquina e seu IP, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Tela de cadastro]

O usuário pode cadastrar a quantidade de máquinas que desejar, toda essa informação já está sendo salva no arquivo TXT. Conforme minha classe `Monitor`:

```
public class Monitor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private ArrayList<Computador> computadores;

  //    public ArrayList<Computador> getComputadores() {
  //        return computadores;
  //    }
   //
   //    public void setComputadores(ArrayList<Computador> computadores) {
  //        this.computadores = computadores;
  //    }
/**
 * Creates new form NovoJFrame
 */
public Monitor() {
    initComponents();

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("registro.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String var = s.nextLine();
            if (var.equals(" ")) {
                String nome = s.nextLine();
                String ip = s.nextLine();
                computadores.add(new Computador(nome, ip));
            }
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    };
}


private void btnGravarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    File arq = new File("registro.txt");
    btnGravar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Condição, verifica se os campo estão vazios.
            if (campoNome.getText().equals("")) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Adicione um nome ao computador!");
                campoNome.requestFocus();
            } else if (campoIP.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Adicione um IP!");
                // Fornece o foco ao cursor da caixa de Texto
                campoIP.requestFocus();
            } else {
                // Tratamento de Erros.
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq, true);
                    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                        bw.write(campoNome.getText() + " ");
                        bw.write(campoIP.getText() + "\n");
                        bw.flush();
                        bw.close();
                    }
                    campoNome.setText("");
                    campoIP.setText("");
                    // Exibe caixa de Dialogo.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Arquivo Gravado com Sucesso!");

                } catch (IOException Erro) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Erro ao Gravar no Arquivo" + Erro);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}                                      

private void btnAbrirMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    btnAbrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Computador cp = new Computador(null, null);
            cp.run();

        }
    });
}                                     

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Monitor().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


}
```

Ainda nesta mesma classe ele abre o arquivo TXT e salva as informações no `ArrayList<Computador> computadores;`

Agora é aí onde está meu problema, quando eu clicar no botão *GERAR*, a aplicação é pra pegar todos os IPs que estão no `ArrayList` e jogar na thread, porem ele não entra no laço que irá fazer isso. Eu coloquei um teste fora do laço e ele executa somente esse teste.

Abaixo está a classe responsável por pegar as informações do array e jogar na thread:

**Classe computador**

```
public class Computador extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable {

private String nome;
private String ip;
//private boolean online;

private Thread processo;

/**
 * Creates new form Computador
 */
public Computador(String n, String i) {

    initComponents();

    nome = n;
    ip = i;
    //online = s;

    CampoNome.setText(n);
    CampoIP.setText(i);
    /*if(online) {
        CampoStatus.setText("Online");
    }else{
        CampoStatus.setText("Offline");
    }*/

    processo = new Thread(this);
    processo.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        ArrayList<Computador> computadores = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < computadores.size(); i++) {
            String addr = computadores.get(i).ip;

            try {
                if (InetAddress.getByName(addr).isReachable(3000)) {
                    String nome = InetAddress.getByName(addr).getHostName();
                    System.out.println("Host " + nome + " (" + addr + ") ativo!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Host " + addr + " inativo!");
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Computador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Computador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Testando");
        try {
            processo.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Computador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está a saída no console, (por enquanto ainda não joguei as informações na interface).

[image: Saída]

A cada IP que ele pegar do `ArrayList`, ele irá executar um computador numa thread e exibir na interface o ícone do computador, o nome dessa máquina, assim como seu IP e seu status.

Alguém pode me ajudar com o desenvolvimento dessa aplicação?

Comment: Sua dúvida tem mais relação com threads, não tem necessidade da tag orientação a objeto.

Comment: Ok de boa Diego. Pois é, meu problema que nao to conseguindo pegar as informaçoes do txt e jogar no arraylist, pra dai jogar na Trhead

Comment: Há um monte de problemas em seu código. Porém como ele está incompleto (e do jeito que você postou, não compila), é difícil lidar com todos. Por favor, poste o código completo das classes `Monitor` e `Computador` (incluindo os `imports` e o `initComponents()`) que daí eu ajeito tudo e posto uma resposta bem legal.

Comment: Victor aqui esta o link onde esta todo o meu projeto > https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5pzlui4lo17fvx6/AADqFltb1rr1rgTOzQQDdMMfa?dl=0

Comment: o projeto  esta compilando, porem so nao executa a funçao do InetAddress dentro da thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Agora é aí onde está meu problema, quando eu clicar no botão GERAR, a
>   aplicação é pra pegar todos os IPs que estão no ArrayList e jogar na
>   thread, porem ele não entra no laço que irá fazer isso

Então, nunca vai entrar porque você tá construindo a collection logo antes de entrar no laço:

```
ArrayList<Computador> computadores = new ArrayList(); //  Aqui tá sem itens!

    for (int i = 0; i < computadores.size(); i++) { // Size é 0 => (i < 0) = false
```

Você precisa iterar na lista de computadores que é atributo da classe Monitor. Para isso, sugiro que você mova esse ArrayList de Computador para uma classe Controller:

```
class ComputadorController {
     private static ArrayList<Computador> computadores = new ArrayList<Computador>();

     public static getComputadores() {
          return computadores;
     }
     public static setComputadores(ArrayList<Computador> computadores) {
          ComputadorController.computadores = computadores;
     }
}
```

Aí é só mudar o construtor de monitor para alimentar esse controller:

```
public Computador(String n, String i) {
    initComponents();

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("registro.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
        String var = s.nextLine();
        if (var.equals(" ")) {
            String nome = s.nextLine();
            String ip = s.nextLine();
            ComputadorController.getComputadores().add(new Computador(nome, ip));
        }
    }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    };
}
```

E no teu laço você vai passar a iterar na lista que foi alimentada pela aplicação:

```
@Override
public void run() {

while (true) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ComputadorController.getComputadores().size(); i++) {
         String addr = ComputadorController.getComputadores().get(i).ip;
```

Minha sugestão é a que menos altera a lógica da tua implementação atual, mas sugiro que você refatore o teu código atentando pra questões de encapsulamento, orientação à objeto, padrões de nomes, e tratamento de exceções.

Espero ter ajudado ^^